# Komodo IDE 7.0 'link on automatic parenthesis closing'

Tags: eclipse, ide, editor, pydev, komodo

Does Komodo IDE have an option similar to PyDev in Eclipse for tabbing out of autocompleted parentheses and quotation marks? I have Komodo set to insert closing quotations and parentheses, but find it annoying to use the arrow keys to move out of them. Is there an option similar to what is found in PyDev below?

Preferences -> Pydev -> Editor -> Typing -> 'Enable link on automatic parenthesis closing'

if not, I'd probably just turn off the feature and try to manually do it, but I found it handy in PyDev.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the following options:

- Remap <kbd>Ctrl + ]</kbd> to <kbd>tab,tab</kbd> in the [key bindings](http://docs.activestate.com/komodo/7.1/prefs.html#Config_Key_Bindings) section of the Komodo preferences.
- Press the <kbd>End</kbd> key to move to the end of the line
- Hold down the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key while pressing the right bracket to jump to the end of the block
- Hold down the [<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key](http://docs.activestate.com/komodo/7.1/defkeybind.html) ([<kbd>Alt</kbd> on OSX](http://docs.activestate.com/komodo/7.1/osxkeybind.html)) while pressing the right arrow to jump to the end of the current statement

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation Paul. Unfortunately, I find all of those more burdensome than the tab key, as is used in PyDev. The Komodo guys have said they would like to implement this feature last time I posted in their forum, but until then, doesn't look like it's an option. Thanks again.

Comment: @YuriHyuga No problem. Another way would be to remap one of the above combinations to `tab,tab` in the [key bindings](http://docs.activestate.com/komodo/7.1/prefs.html#Config_Key_Bindings) section of the Komodo preferences.